# Database not created

Tags: database, postgresql

I installed postgresql and tried to create new database but couldn't succeed in creating database:

```
Server [localhost]:
Database [postgres]:
Port [5433]:
Username [postgres]:
psql (9.2.17)
WARNING: Console code page (850) differs from Windows code page (1252)
         8-bit characters might not work correctly. See psql reference
         page "Notes for Windows users" for details.
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# createdb gps_heatmap
postgres-# \l
                                          List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |       Collate       |        Ctype        |   Access privileges
-----------+----------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------------
 database4 | postgres | UTF8     | English_Canada.1252 | English_Canada.1252 |
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | English_Canada.1252 | English_Canada.1252 |
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | English_Canada.1252 | English_Canada.1252 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |                     |                     | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | English_Canada.1252 | English_Canada.1252 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |                     |                     | postgres=CTc/postgres
(4 rows)


postgres-#
```

Database is not created . I couldnt solve this problem. Help needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `;` use

```
createdb gps_heatmap;
```